# Getting an error "Feature Layer Error", with automating ArcGIS Online Dashboard

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer, dashboard

I created a dashboard using ArcGIS online and am in the process of automating the dashboard to update on its own but kept getting this error:

`''FeatureLayerCollection' object has no attribute 'replicas'''`

While searching for help online, I stumbled on this: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/create-replica-using-arcgis-api-for-python-error/td-p/861637 and enabled all the editing capabilities and saved. After running the script, it says successful but all the checked editing boxes become unchecked.

How do I leave them permanently checked?

Comment: how are you automating the dashboard? Is it the new dashboard, or classic? What is the platform used to work with scripts?

Add these details for better understanding..

Comment: Am using ArcGIS official Python scripts for the automation. "OverwriteFS"